# Compilation order in make rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a compilation rule as follows,

```
    $(compiled_objs) : $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
```

It creates .o dso objects from specific .cpp files in src_base and works fine.

Question:
My question is that is there a way in gnu Makefiles to sort the order in which %.cpp files are processed. For example, in each src_base, i have a file called xxxLast.cpp and i want to create the object for *Last.cpp after all other .cpp files from $src_dir directory has already been processed.

Use-Case:
My use case is not common but i want to embedd the md5sum of all other .o objects in xxxLast.cpp file for which i can add additional handling in my rule.

I haven't done much work on makefiles. Help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere else in your makefile you'll have a target that depends on `$(compiled_objs)`:

```
all_objects: $(compiled_objs)
```

Make will build the prerequisites of any target in the order they are listed.  So if you want a particular object to be built last, then you just put it at the end of the `compiled_objs` macro.

Be aware that during parallel builds make will still walk the commands to run in the same order, BUT due to parallelization effects they may actually run in a different order, or at least you can't know that the last one will be started after all the previous ones have completed.

For your situation I really don't recommend just stucking the last object at the end and hoping.  You should define this relationship explicitly using make rules, so:

```
all_objects: xxxLast.o

xxxLast.o: $(compiled_objs-but-not-xxxLast.o)
        ...generate md5sums for $^...

xxxLast.o $(compiled_objs-but-not-xxxLast.o): $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. This solution works. I have a related question. Can I call recursive make using make -W <src>/*.cpp <obj>/*.o ? I want the respective cpp file to transform into the same respective .o file but want to use it recursively. The reason being that in some case, i just want to call recursive rule on specific src_dir with number of source files based on specific condition. I want all objects being rebuild.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question.  If you want to rebuild a specific set of object files, you can add them to the make line: `$(MAKE) <obj>/foo.o <obj>/bar.o <obj>/baz.o`  If you want them to always be rebuilt, but only the object files, you must add a `-W` in front of each one.  You can also add the `-B` flag but if any of those objects depend on generated files they'll be regenerated.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't explain it well. The thing you mentioned will definitely work but my question is little different. Since I have many different src_dirs and each has N .cpp files that creates N .o files. Can I make a recursive call with src_dir and it will rebuild all the .cpp files inside that specific dir.

Comment: Certainly you can do that.